# MongoDB - Limit within a group with reduce

Tags: php, mongodb

I am new to Mongodb and I am wondering how to limit results within a group call (PHP).
After some researches I found out that the only way is to write a "reducer"

This is what I currently have

```
    $reduce = "function (obj, prev) { ";
    $reduce .= "if(prev.count >= 2){";
    $reduce .= "prev.mailSubject = obj.mailSubject;";
    $reduce .= "}";
    $reduce .= "prev.count+=1;";
    $reduce .="}";
    $res = $this->db->forms->group(
                array('formid' => true),
                array('mailSubject' => ''),''),
                $reduce                                         
            );
```

It seems that is not reducing anything, I still got the same results as i don't put the if in. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure if you really understood the concept of `group` and/or the purpose of the reduce-function. Can you please explain what exactly you try to do?

Comment: i am trying to execute the following sql query: select * from forms group by formid limit 2, 100

Comment: Then a reduce function is the wrong approach, because a reduce-function is unaware of how many documents were already processed.

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: have you managed to solve the problem maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MongoDB equivalent to SQL `LIMIT` are usually the cursor methods `limit()` and `skip()`. Unfortunately the PHP drivers `MongoCollection::group` returns the result set and not a cursor. But what you can do instead is use [`MongoCollection::aggregate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php) and use an aggregation pipeline of three operators:

1. [$group by your grouping criteria](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)
2. [$limit to only take the first 100](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit)
3. [$skip to ignore the first two](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/skip/#pipe._S_skip)

These examples use the JSON syntax for the data structures, but it shouldn't be hard to convert them to the associative array syntax of PHP.

**By the way:** You aren't sorting your results. Skipping usually only makes sense when your results are sorted by some criteria, because otherwise you don't know which documents will be skipped. The order in which documents are returned by MongoDB is unspecified. It might look like insertion order in your development environment, but this is not guaranteed and will stop happening reliably after some removals, updates and insertions. When you want to sort your results, add the [$sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) to the aggregation pipeline between point 1 and 2.